# Who is this superhero/villain in the picture?

Tags: dc, super-hero

I found this miniature of a superhero or villain. It's costume looks like a mix of Red Robin, The Owl and Moon Knight, but I can't figure out who he is. Does anyone know? 
[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This appears to be Doctor Mid-Nite

[image]

As noted by RDFozz in the comments the foreground image above appears to the the Pieter Cross version of Doctor Mid-Nite which resembles your figure,  while the background appears to be the Charles McNider version.  The Beth Chapel version maintains the black cowl with the crescent moon but otherwise is very different from the other two:

[image]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Mid-Nite)

> Doctor Mid-Nite (also Doctor Midnight) is a fictional superhero physician in DC Comics. The figure has been represented in the comics by three different individuals, Charles McNider, Beth Chapel, and Pieter Anton Cross. Dr. Mid-Nite was originally created by writer Charles Reizenstein and artist Stanley Josephs Aschmeier in 1941. The hero, represented first by Charles McNider, appeared for the first time in All-American Comics #25 (April 1941).
>
> All three versions of Doctor Mid-Nite have exhibited the same basic features: a cowled costume featuring a crescent moon symbol, keen ability to see in the darkness at the cost of near or total blindness in sunlight, the use of special visors and “blackout” smoke bombs to gain tactical advantage in combat, a high degree of skill in martial arts, and jobs as physicians serving both normal human beings and "metahuman" superheroes. Additionally, two of the doctors have been accompanied by sidekick owls.

Comment: Based on the details of the costume (the tie-down on his thighs and the silver buttons on the tunic), I'd guess this is the Pieter Cross version (the small foreground image in the above picture, rather than the larger background figure).

Answer (score 42):

This is Doctor Mid-Nite. Has the owl, crescent moon, and red tunic.

[image]